# 'Indentation Error - expected an indented block' when dealing with header

Tags: python, sockets, http-headers

Since I'm new to programming, there might be other mistakes in the code I haven't detected, so if you notice any rookie mistakes or bad style please point out. I'm trying to implement a simple web server, but keep getting an Indentation Error at the part where server creates an HTTP response message consisting of the requested file preceded by header lines.

```
from socket import *
import sys

host = 'localhost'
serverPort = int(sys.argv[1])
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind((host,serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

    try:
        #if received correct stuff
        File_Wanted = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        File_Name = File_Wanted.split()[1]
        #open and read line in index.htm
        File = open('index.htm','r')
        output = File.read()
        #should I close it here or somewhere else?
        File.close()

        #take care of header first 
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n')

        #looks good, then send to client(browser)
        for i in range(0, len(output)):
        connectionSocket.send(output[i]) 
        connectionSocket.close()


    IOError:
    #Send response message for file not found
        connectionSocket.send('404 Not Found')                       
    #Close client socket       
        connectionSocket.close()                            


serverSocket.close()
```

When I build on sublime, I got.

```
connectionSocket.send(output[i]) 
^
```

IndentationError: expect an idented block

Comment: Python uses whitespace for defining blocks, you need to indent the lines after the `for` statement

Comment: Try an indentation after serverSocket.close()

Comment: indent lines after `for` loop for code that should be in the `for`

Comment: and you're clearly missed `except` keyword in try-except block (`IOError` line). Should be `except IOError:`.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses whitespace for defining blocks, you need to indent the lines after the `for` statement:

```
for i in range(0, len(output)):
    connectionSocket.send(output[i]) 
    connectionSocket.close()
```

and you need an `except` statement before checking the error:

```
except IOError:
```